# Shaped Ray Cast for C++

Tags: geometry, collision-detection, computational-geometry, raycasting

I'm looking for a (preferably free) lib for the following:
I want to do a Trace Ray through my scene, but not for a single starting point, but rather a starting shape.

So instead of having the origin being a point and the trace a line, I want the origin to be a shape (say, circle) and the trace a cylinder.

I found this page here: https://github.com/jslee02/awesome-collision-detection , but I still could not find this feature.

Unreal has UWorld::SweepMultiByChannel, which is pretty much what I want (but I'm not in UE...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIAGameWorks PhysX seems to have all the answers that I need.